# How To take n number as input in multiple line of input

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want to take n number as input then have multiple line of input as user entered n before.

here my code is:

```
num=int(input)

for i in range(0,2)    
    for x in range(0,num)
```

for example , I need to take n from user input to know how many lines I have to go. each line I have 2 element in a raw. here user inputed  n as 3, so we have 3 line of input which each one has 2 elements. for example: n=3 first line=[1 ,10] second line=[7, 3] third line=[5,2]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if at all possible. As it stands, I do not understand what you mean by _"I want to take n number as input then have multiple line of input as user entered n before."_, nor how the code you have provided fits into this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this right, I think this is the solution you're looking for.

```
num=input("Please specify how many inputs you want to take in: ")
arr = []

print("Prompting for "+str(num)+" inputs:")
for i in range(0,int(num)):
    arr.append(input(str(i+1)+": "))

print("Inputs as indexes in array are:")
count=0
for k in arr:
    print(str(count)+": "+str(k))
    count=count+1
```

The idea is that you prompt the user for a certain amount of inputs and loop through that number of times, adding the additional input to an array each time. The array later then could be accessed as if it were multiple lines, if I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: hello thanks for your answer,

I need to take n from user input to know how many lines I have to go. each line I have 2 element in a raw.
here user input n as 3, so we have 3 line of input which each one has 2 elements.
for example:
n=3
first line=[1 ,10]
second line=[7, 3]
third line=[5,2]

.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have some data like this

```
1
a b c ...
2
d e f ...
3
g h i ...
...
...
...
n
```

and you don't know n

try this:

```
while True:
    try:
        for i in range(x):
            # do something
    except EOFError:
        break
```

you read input from stdin and when "you run out of input" python throws a `EOFError`. `EOF` is end of file. What it basically means is that there is no more input to take. When you get this error (this is what the `except` clause does) you break out of the loop.

**Edit after reading the comment**

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    a, b = map(int, input().split())
```

Comment: hello thanks for your answer, I need to take n from user input to know how many lines I have to go. each line I have 2 element in a raw. here user input n as 3, so we have 3 line of input which each one has 2 elements. for example: n=3 first line=[1 ,10] second line=[7, 3] third line=[5,2]

Answer (score 0):

You want to read *numbers* and Python offers you a function, `input`, that reads *strings*, so the first thing that you want to do is to write a function that reads a string and returns a number

```
def intinput(prompt, n_of_trials=1):
    ntry = 0
    while True:
        n = input(prompt)
        ntry:
            return int(n)
        except ValueError:
            ntry +=1
            if ntry <= n_of_trials:
                print('Error converting "%s" to an integer, please try again'%n)
            else:
                raise ValueError
```

where `n_of_trials`, a default argument, is how many errors will be recovered before failing ungracefully.

With this function in our bag and if I understand correctly your request, your code can be organized as follows

```
n = intinput('How many numbers are you going to input? ', 2)
list_of_numbers = [intinput('please input no. %d/%d: '%(i+1,n)) for i in range(n)]
```

Example runs:

```
In [18]:     n = intinput('How many numbers are you going to input? ', 2)
    ...:     list_of_numbers = [intinput('please input no. %d/%d: '%(i+1,n)) for i in range(n)]
How many numbers are you going to input? 4
please input no. 1/4: 1
please input no. 2/4: 2
please input no. 3/4: 3
please input no. 4/4: 4

In [19]: print(list_of_numbers)
[1, 2, 3, 4]

In [20]:     n = intinput('How many numbers are you going to input? ', 2)
    ...:     list_of_numbers = [intinput('please input no. %d/%d: '%(i+1,n)) for i in range(n)]
How many numbers are you going to input? 4
please input no. 1/4: pip
Error converting "pip" to an integer, please try again
please input no. 1/4: 1
please input no. 2/4: pep
Error converting "pep" to an integer, please try again
please input no. 2/4: 2
please input no. 3/4: pop
Error converting "pop" to an integer, please try again
please input no. 3/4: 55
please input no. 4/4: 11

In [21]: print(list_of_numbers)
[1, 2, 55, 11]
```